# "Why my character cannot move in VB.Net?" [EDITED]

Tags: vb.net

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate for RPG game. Unfortunately, when the character doesn't have any items after having some talk to NPC, my character suddenly cannot move. I dunno how to make it move.. Here's my codes..

There are my codes for movements:

```
Dim walk As Integer

Private Sub room1_KeyDown(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyDown

    'Up
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.W Then
        walk = walk + 1
        If walk = 5 Then
            walk = 1
        End If

        If walk = 1 Then
            picmc.Image = My.Resources.yuiUp.mc10
            moveUp()
        End If
        If walk = 2 Then
            picmc.Image = My.Resources.yuiUp.mc11
            moveUp()
        End If
        If walk = 3 Then
            picmc.Image = My.Resources.yuiUp.mc12
            moveUp()
        End If
        If walk = 4 Then
            picmc.Image = My.Resources.yuiUp.mc11
            moveUp()
        End If
    End If

    'Down
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.S Then
        walk = walk + 1
        If walk = 5 Then
            walk = 1
        End If
        If walk = 1 Then
            picmc.Image = My.Resources.yuiDown.mc1
            moveDown()
        End If
        If walk = 2 Then
            picmc.Image = My.Resources.yuiDown.mc2
            moveDown()
        End If
        If walk = 3 Then
            picmc.Image = My.Resources.yuiDown.mc3
            moveDown()
        End If
        If walk = 4 Then
            picmc.Image = My.Resources.yuiDown.mc2
            moveDown()
        End If
    End If

    'Left
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.A Then
        walk = walk + 1
        If walk = 5 Then
            walk = 1
        End If
        If walk = 1 Then
            picmc.Image = My.Resources.yuiLeft.mc4
            moveLeft()
        End If
        If walk = 2 Then
            picmc.Image = My.Resources.yuiLeft.mc5
            moveLeft()
        End If
        If walk = 3 Then
            picmc.Image = My.Resources.yuiLeft.mc6
            moveLeft()
        End If
        If walk = 4 Then
            picmc.Image = My.Resources.yuiLeft.mc5
            moveLeft()
        End If
    End If

    'Right
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.D Then
        walk = walk + 1
        If walk = 5 Then
            walk = 1
        End If
        If walk = 1 Then
            picmc.Image = My.Resources.yuiRight.mc7
            moveRight()
        End If
        If walk = 2 Then
            picmc.Image = My.Resources.yuiRight.mc8
            moveRight()
        End If
        If walk = 3 Then
            picmc.Image = My.Resources.yuiRight.mc9
            moveRight()
        End If
        If walk = 4 Then
            picmc.Image = My.Resources.yuiRight.mc8
            moveRight()
        End If
    End If
```

There are my sub functions:

```
'Moving character
Sub moveUp()
    picmc.Top -= 20
End Sub

Sub moveDown()
    picmc.Top += 20
End Sub

Sub moveRight()
    picmc.Left += 20
End Sub

Sub moveLeft()
    picmc.Left -= 20
End Sub
```

This area is my PROBLEM!! when the two items are still active in the game (let's say the user didn't get those items) he/she needs to find it but the problem is.. CHARACTER IS NOT MOVE ITSELF! :(

```
   Private Sub btnOldie_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnOldie.Click
    If tooth.Visible = False AndAlso comb.Visible = False Then
        lblDialog.Text = "Find the oldie to the next room."
        Me.Hide()
        room2.Show()
    Else
        noItems()
    End If
End Sub
```

This is my function for NoItems():

```
Sub noItems()
    btnTooth.Visible = False
    btnComb.Visible = False
    btnOldie.Visible = False
    btnOk.Visible = True
    lblDialog.Text = "Find that thing first."
End Sub
```

Comment: There's way too much code there. You need to use the debugger, i.e. set breakpoints and step through the code and examine the application state, to narrow down the issue much more than that. If you haven't used the debugger already, which I suspect is the case, then doing so may even allow you to solve the issue for yourself. You should also read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: We can't troubleshoot this problem with the code you've posted.  I see you have multiple forms involved.  A couple of possibilities are (1) you have an instance problem where you are showing forms with "new" instances when you shouldn't be, or (2) something else has the focus and therefore your "move" code isn't being triggered.

Comment: Your edit is a step in the right direction, but it is still difficult to understand what your code is trying to do. I would suggest you learn how to use the `Select Case` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is more complicated than you might think. The thing is, you don't need a snippet of code. You need a new way to look at your code.

What you want is a design pattern named "States".

[Here's a link](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/state.html), just for you.

Just to help you start, here's some pointers. Your character can do many things. You can divide those things in states. Maybe your character can stay idle, walk, run, jump, fall and die. All of these are states, and by enforcing those states you kinda have a mask that will "change the rules" your character abides for any of these instances. For an example, your character may have different animations for every one of these states. It's max speed might be different for these, too. Maybe he becomes vulnerable or invincible in some situations.

By enforcing states, you create a strict structure around your character's behavior, which is both easier to custom and harder to make exceptions to. Most games use this pattern a lot.

Good programming!